# Contact form 7 not aligning checkboxes correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, checkbox

I am using contact form 7, when I create checkboxes they don't align properly, I've attempted to use the fix everyone else does with the list items and display:block but that wont work.

Here is some sample code

```
<span style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
<p style="padding-left: 21px; padding-bottom: 0px;">Please let me know about forthcoming events I might take part in:</p>
[checkbox local-events class:checkbox "local events (e.g. short walks, fundraising events)"]

[checkbox challenge-events class:checkbox "Challenge events (e.g. overseas treks, sky diving)"]</span>
```

Here is how it looks, i want the checkbox and the label to align themselves.

[image]

Comment: what if you take the padding off of the `<p>`

Comment: The padding isn’t affecting it

Comment: p is a block element. what if you insert your checkbox inside of `p`? or try use `label` instead of `p`